# Extracting sentences in a text using a list of words expressions does not really work

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Hello I have a list of words. The words can be complex words or verbal sentences/phrasal verbs and etc...

I would like to search inside a text if those words/expressions are present.

I come up with this exemple for small data but I have huge data and I find that at times the script extract sentences which contains part of words of the expressions present in my list :

For example, 'pas trop lumineux', there is a high change that a sentence containing only 'lumineux is exported'

```
lexique = ['attarder mental','trop laid', 'pas assez grand', 'trop méchant']

sentences = ['il est attardé mental', 'il est trop beau', 'Il est pas assez grand']
sentences_other =[]

for sent in sentences:
      mytokens = nlp(sent)
      mytokens2 = [word.lemma_.lower().strip() for word in mytokens if word.pos_ != "SPACE"]
      d_sent[sent] = " ".join(mytokens2)

    #print(d_sent)

    for k, v in d_sent.items():
      for w in lexique : 
        #print(word)
        if w in v:
          #if k not in sentences_with_word_mais:
          if k not in sentences_other:
            #sentences_with_word_mais.append(k)
            sentences_other.append(k)
```

Comment: 1- Is your nlp and word.lemma set to your language which is other than eng? 2- If you add "sentences = list(dict.fromkeys(sentences))" after definition of sentences you can get ride of the "if k not in sentences_other:" since there will be no more duplicate in your sentences to check later

Comment: yes, set to french. I used spacy for french.